# Function for extracting a name from a path;

Tags: c, string, extract, cut

Hi everyone I have a question: I want to write a function that takes a string in form of char* which represents a path for example: "/1/2/3/4/5"(always starting with a /). The function has two purposes to extract(and return) the first name and to cut that name from the list.

As with the prev example /1/2/3/4/5 -> /2/3/4/5 and the function will return "1";

Can anyone give me any ideas how could i structure it I'm pretty new two C and the whole concept of a string as a char pointer shakes me a little

Comment: You're going to have to take a stab at this problem. Hint: `strtok` on `"/"`.

Comment: You don't need to dynamically allocate memory to make this work.  All you need to do is pass in a pointer to the string so that where it points to can be changed.  https://onlinegdb.com/r117Dp6ow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it starts with a slash, you can start from the second position:

```
char* extract (char *path)
{
    int i;
    char *first;
    for(i = 1; path[i] != '/'; i++); //this for is only to get to the second slash
    
    path[i] = '\0'; // here you erase the second slash
   
    first = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(&path[1]) + 1)); //allocate space for the string plus the '\0'
    strcpy(first, &path[1]);  //copy what you wanted to extract
    strcpy(&path[1], &path[i + 1]); // copy the things that remained back to the second position.
   //The first position is still the same slash and keeps unaltered
    return first;
}
```

You could test your function like this:

```
int main()
{
    char c[] =  "/1/2/3/4/5";
    printf("%s %s\n", extract(c), c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strcpy(&path[1], &path[i + 1]);` causes an Abort Trap: 6. I'm not sure why.

Comment: @Schwern strcpy's documentation says "The behavior is undefined if the strings overlap." https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy  so when the text after the second slash is copied back to the first slash bad things can happen.

Comment: @Schwern it can be fixed by using memove instead of strcpy.  memmove's documentation says "The objects may overlap" https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memmove

Answer (score 0):

Removing the first element can be done with just pointer arithmetic.

```
int i;
for(i = 1; path[i] != '/'; i++);
path += i;
```

You want both the first part of the path, and to change the path. You can't return two things in C. Instead, we can use a double pointer to change where `path` points to.

```
char* extract_first_directory(char **path) {
    // Find the index of the second /
    int i;
    for(i = 1; (*path)[i] != '/'; i++);

    // Allocate enough memory for the first part and a null byte.
    // The length of the first part is i - 1. We need an extra byte for the
    // null byte so i - 1 + 1 is just i.
    char *first = malloc(sizeof(char) * i);

    // Copy just the first portion.
    strncpy(first, *path + 1, i-1);

    // Add the null byte to `first` because stpncpy doesn't do that.
    first[i] = '\0';

    // Move the start of path to the second /
    *path += i;

    return first;
}
```

The caveat is that since we moved where `path` points to, if we `free(path)` it will leak memory. So we keep the original pointer.

```
int main() {
    // Can't change "/1/2/3/4/5", it has to be copied to stack memory.
    char *path = strdup("/1/2/3/4/5");

    // Keep the original pointer so it can be freed.
    char *new_path = path;
    char *first = extract_first_directory(&new_path);
    printf("first: %s, new: %s, path: %s\n", first, new_path, path);

    // This will also free new_path.
    free(path);

    return 0;
}
```

---

An alternative might be to instead do all the splitting at once with [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) and return a struct which contains each path element as an array.

```
typedef struct {
    char *path;
    char **entries;
    size_t num_entries;
    size_t max_size;
} Path;

Path *Path_new() {
    Path *path = malloc(sizeof(Path));

    path->path = NULL;
    // Starting with some space allocated makes extending simpler.
    path->entries = malloc(sizeof(char**) * 2);
    path->max_size = 2;
    path->num_entries = 0;

    return path;
}

void Path_append_entry(Path *path, char *entry) {
    // Double the size as needed.
    if( path->max_size <= path->num_entries ) {
        path->entries = realloc(path->entries, sizeof(char**) * 2 * path->max_size);
        path->max_size *= 2;
    }
    path->entries[ path->num_entries ] = entry;
    path->num_entries++;
}

void Path_init(Path *path, const char *original) {
    // Copy the path because strtok works by replacing the / with nulls.
    path->path = strdup(original);

    for(
        char *token = strtok(path->path, "/");
        token;
        token = strtok(NULL, "/")
    ) {
        puts(token);
        Path_append_entry(path, token);
    }
}

void Path_print(Path *path, int i) {
    for(; i < path->num_entries; i++ ) {
        printf("/");
        printf("%s", path->entries[i]);
    }
    puts("");
}

int main() {
    char path[] = "/1/2/3/4/5";

    Path *p = Path_new();
    Path_init(p, path);
    printf("first: %s\n", p->entries[0]);
    Path_print(p, 1);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to dynamically allocate memory you can edit the string in place.  If you move the stuff between the first slash and second slash back one then there is a space for a string termination character.  That way you don't need to free the pointer returned from the function.

```
char *extract(char **path)
{
    // save the start of the string
    char *first = *path;
    if (!*first) return first;
    // find the second slash or the end of the string
    char *rest = strchr(first+1,'/');
    if (!rest) rest = first+strlen(first);
    // move the stuff between the first and second slash back one
    memmove(first,first+1,rest-first);
    *(rest-1)='\0';
    // set the output parameters
    *path = rest;
    return first;
}
```

Here is a full sample program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// This function asumes the first character is a slash
// that first character is overwritten so it had better be a slash...
// 'path' is a pointer to the string so that we can change where it points
char *extract(char **path)
{
    // we repoint path before we return so we need a pointer to the start
    char *first = *path;
    // if the string is empty then don't do anything
    if (!*first) return first;
    // look for a slash after that first one
    char *rest = strchr(first+1,'/');
    // if we didn't find a second slash, point to the end of the string
    if (!rest) rest = first+strlen(first);
    // move the bit between the first and second slash back one to get rid the the leading slash
    memmove(first,first+1,rest-first);
    // make sure the end of the first bit has a string terminator
    *(rest-1)='\0';
    // update the path to the new starting place
    *path = rest;
    // return the first bit
    return first;
}

int main()
{

    char a0[] = ""; // somewhere writable to store the string
    char *s0=a0; // a pointer to the start of the string that can be changed
    printf("before: \"%s\"\n",s0);
    printf("return: \"%s\"\n",extract(&s0));
    printf("after:  \"%s\"\n",s0);
    puts("---");
    
    char a1[] = "/"; // somewhere writable to store the string
    char *s1=a1; // a pointer to the start of the string that can be changed
    printf("before: \"%s\"\n",s1);
    printf("return: \"%s\"\n",extract(&s1));
    printf("after:  \"%s\"\n",s1);
    puts("---");
    
    char a2[] = "//"; // somewhere writable to store the string
    char *s2=a2; // a pointer to the start of the string that can be changed
    printf("before: \"%s\"\n",s2);
    printf("return: \"%s\"\n",extract(&s2));
    printf("after:  \"%s\"\n",s2);
    puts("---");
    
    char a3[] = "/asd"; // somewhere writable to store the string
    char *s3=a3; // a pointer to the start of the string that can be changed
    printf("before: \"%s\"\n",s3);
    printf("return: \"%s\"\n",extract(&s3));
    printf("after:  \"%s\"\n",s3);
    puts("---");
    
    char a4[] = "/asd/qwe"; // somewhere writable to store the string
    char *s4=a4; // a pointer to the start of the string that can be changed
    printf("before: \"%s\"\n",s4);
    printf("return: \"%s\"\n",extract(&s4));
    printf("after:  \"%s\"\n",s4);
    puts("---");
    
    char a5[] = "/asd/qwe/zxc"; // somewhere writable to store the string
    char *s5=a5; // a pointer to the start of the string that can be changed
    printf("before:   \"%s\"\n",a5);
    printf("return 1: \"%s\"\n",extract(&s5));
    printf("after  1: \"%s\"\n",s5);
    printf("return 2: \"%s\"\n",extract(&s5));
    printf("after  2: \"%s\"\n",s5);
    printf("return 3: \"%s\"\n",extract(&s5));
    printf("after  3: \"%s\"\n",s5);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Try it at https://onlinegdb.com/r1JKsTpsv